# How to trigger client app function from cloud?

Tags: c#, server, .net-core, cloud

I'm trying to create cloud base solution to trigger client functions using C# (.net core) and I tried websocket with signalR and google cloud messaging. I'm looking for any other solution to do above job. Please let me know if there are any free new technologies to do this in C# (.net core)

Comment: Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) have notification capabilities. This may be something you want to look into.

Comment: I read the description of your app, but I can't fully paint the picture in my head.  Who is calling whom?  How do signalR and google cloud messaging fail to meet your goal?